# Is there an option in Jenkins to find a particular value from a console output by passing a key and post it in slack channel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am currently using
Slack Notification Plugin(2.18) and integrated with jenkins and it works well with the default functionalities.

But, I am trying to find a particular value from console output of a job by passing a key. For example key is "Unique_ID" and I need to get its value from console output and post it in slack channel.

console output will look like:

`00:23:53 Started by user user1
 00:24:23 INFO: Unique_ID: 12uy87tg Entity: com.net.qa.rest.domain`

Basically, I want to get the value `12uy87tg` in slack channel when the build succeeded/failed by passing `Unique_ID` in the job config.

Can someone help me on this how to do it or let me know if there is an option in jenkins to post it in slack channel.

Tried the below code in Groovy Postbuild:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// Define the regex to extract the value you want
pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*Unique_ID: (.*) Entity.*");

uniqueId = null;
reader = null;

// Open the log of the build in a buffer
try{
  reader = new BufferedReader(manager.build.getLogReader())

  // Read the buffer and look for a match of the regex
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
       // If there is a match, the value is stored and the research is over
       uniqueId = matcher.group(1);
       break;
    }
  }
}
finally{
  // Close the buffer
  if (reader != null) {
    reader.close();
  }
}
// If a value has been found, it is passed to the slack plugin
if (uniqueId != null){
  // Get the instance of the slack plugin
def slack = manager.build.project.publishers.find{ k, v -> v.class.name == 'jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier' }?.value
  // Set the custom message in Slack
 slack.setIncludeCustomMessage(true)
 slack.setCustomMessage("Unique_ID: "+uniqueId)
}
```

But the above code gave the below error

```
16:36:36 ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
16:36:36 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1$_run_closure1.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder) values: [org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder@5df675b1]
16:36:36 Possible solutions: any(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:286)
16:36:36    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
16:36:36    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
16:36:36    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.BooleanReturningMethodInvoker.invoke(BooleanReturningMethodInvoker.java:51)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.BooleanClosureWrapper.call(BooleanClosureWrapper.java:53)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.find(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3934)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$193.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
16:36:36    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
16:36:36    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:35)
16:36:36    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
16:36:36    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
16:36:36    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
16:36:36    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:350)
16:36:36    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.perform(GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java:380)
16:36:36    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
16:36:36    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
16:36:36    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
16:36:36    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
16:36:36    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
16:36:36    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
16:36:36    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
16:36:36    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
16:36:36    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
16:36:41 [Slack Notifications] found #8905 as previous completed, non-aborted build
16:36:41 [Slack Notifications] will send OnSuccessNotification because build matches and user preferences allow it
16:36:41 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a groovy script.

First, download and install the [Groovy plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin), and then add a step "Execute system Groovy script" in your job.

The script will be something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// Define the regex to extract the value you want
pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*Unique_ID: (.*) Entity.*");

uniqueId = null;
reader = null;

// Open the log of the build in a buffer
try{
  reader = new BufferedReader(build.getLogReader())

  // Read the buffer and look for a match of the regex
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
       // If there is a match, the value is stored and the research is over
       uniqueId = matcher.group(1);
       break;
    }
  }
}
finally{
  // Close the buffer
  if (reader != null) {
    reader.close();
  }
}

// If a value has been found, it is passed to the slack plugin
if (uniqueId != null){
  // Get the instance of the slack plugin
  def slack = build.project.publishers.find{ k, v -> v.class.name == 'jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier' }?.value
  // Set the custom message in Slack
  slack.setIncludeCustomMessage(true)
  slack.setCustomMessage("Unique_ID: "+uniqueId)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SmartTom, Can I do it in Groovy Postbuild  in post-build actions section?

Comment: @Syed Yes, you can use this script with [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin). But you need to replace `build.getLogReader()` with `manager.build.getLogReader()` and `build.project.publishers` with `manager.build.project.publishers`.

Comment: Thanks @SmartTom,
I am getting this error after doing all these:
`15:56:30 ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
15:56:30 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1$_run_closure1.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder) values: [org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder@6d32604d]
15:56:30 Possible solutions: any(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)`

Do you have an idea here?

Comment: Even with "Execute system groovy script". I am getting same type of exception. Will you be able to help here?
`5:36:26 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
15:36:26 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1$_run_closure1.call() is applicable for argument types: (jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier) values: [jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier@4ee0d9c4]
15:36:26 Possible solutions: any(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
`

Comment: @Syed Can you provide your code in an edit of your question ?

Comment: @Syed Which version of groovy do you use ?

Comment: Groovy version is 2.4.11. ```Also to note am using 1. maven job 2. added the script in post steps "execute system groovy script" as am unable to find this option in build steps in maven job..```

**_I see it works on freestyle job but this exception occurs in maven job_** @SmartTom

Comment: @Syed Alright, with your last given information, I have been able to reproduce your issue. The problem came from the difference between maven job and freestyle job on how it handle their list of publishers. So, replace `build.project.publishers.find` with `build.project.publishers.toMap().find` and it will solve your issue.

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot @SmartTom 
Please do share with me some documents link if you feel anything that is lacking in me. I would love to improve myself.